# Why Is This ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Code Not Failing My Test?

Tags: c#, multithreading, tdd, threadpool

The code in question

```
public void StartPlaying()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ignoredState =>
    {
        while (_playlist.Count > 0)
        {
            var audioFile = _playlist.Dequeue();

            if (StartedPlaying != null)
                StartedPlaying(this, new TypedAudioFileEventArgs(audioFile));

            audioFile.SoundPlayer.PlaySync();
            audioFile.SoundPlayer.Dispose();

            if (StoppedPlaying != null)
                StoppedPlaying(this, new TypedAudioFileEventArgs(audioFile));
        }
    });
}
```

and my test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void StartPlayIsCalledTwice_OnlyRunningOnce()
{
    int timeBetweenPlays = 0; 
    var target = new TypedAudioFilePlayer(timeBetweenPlays);

    target.AddFile(TypedAudioFileCreator.CreateWord(1, "bl"));
    target.StartedPlaying += StartedPlaying_Once;

    target.StartPlaying();
    target.StartPlaying();
}

private bool _once = false;
private void StartedPlaying_Once(object sender, TypedAudioFileEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_once)
        _once = true;
    else
        Assert.Fail("Should not be called more than once!");
}
```

I believe my unit test should fail, judging by the MSDN description of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`:

> Queues a method for execution. The method executes when a thread pool thread becomes available.

The default ThreadPool size is 512, so two threads should immediately be available to process the StartPlaying call. I believe my code should fail since I haven't provided any safeguards from race conditions in which both threads can access the same resource.

What's happening here?

Comment: try declaring _once as volatile...

Comment: @Mitch: Tried it, test still passes. I like how what should technically be a good thing (test passing) is turning out to be a source of fear and confusion (WHY are you passing!?). Heh, software methodologies are fun.

Comment: Even if there weren't race conditions in this code, the Assert will be raised on a different thread to the one executing the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `StartedPlaying` event is only raised if StartPlaying is called when there are items to play.

`_playlist.Dequeue();` dequeues the file you enqueue.  Therefore the second time you get to `while (_playlist.Count > 0)` it will immediately fail, passing the second call to `StartPlaying` straight through without raising the event.

Also, as Bruno Silva points out, the thread spawned by the second call to `StartPlaying` may not have a chance to execute anything before the test exits.

For what it's worth, there are <del>about a million</del> at least 2 threading mistakes in this code also:

```
// Where did _playlist come from?  Is it shared state among the player threads?
// If so, all access to it should be in locks, since queues are not thread safe
while (_playlist.Count > 0) 


// Both of these start threads and then immediately return.  
// The test will probably exit before either of those threads do anything much
    target.StartPlaying();
    target.StartPlaying();
}
```

If you want to properly unit test, you need to define preconditions, expectations, actions, and postconditions:

- **Preconditions:** you have an initialized TypedAudioFilePlayer with one file queued:

  `var target = new TypedAudioFilePlayer(timeBetweenPlays);`
  `target.AddFile(TypedAudioFileCreator.CreateWord(1, "bl"));`
- **Expectations:** The StartedPlaying event will be raised only once if StartPlaying is called twice

  `target.StartedPlaying += StartedPlaying_Once;`
- **Actions:** The StartPlaying method will be called twice:

  `target.StartPlaying();`
  `target.StartPlaying();`
- **Postconditions:** The `StartedPlaying` event was only raised once:

  `private bool _once = false;`

  `private void StartedPlaying_Once(object sender, TypedAudioFileEventArgs e)`
  `{`
  `if (!_once)`
  `_once = true;`
  `else`
  `Assert.Fail("Should not be called more than once!");`
  `}`

Now, your test succeeds.  That's not good in this case, because of what I explain above.  You need to get your test to a failing state by eliminating the queue bug and race condition, then work on making the test pass the *right* way.

Comment: A million? I thought i'm just missing a lock that I haven't written yet for the sake of writing a failing unit test first. That's what my question is about, getting the test in a consistently failing state before I add the lock.

Comment: The test cannot reliably pass (or fail, in this case) while there are race conditions.

Comment: Excellent point, I think my approach to unit testing a threaded function was clearly misguided. +1

Comment: Not at all- you are just going about it in a way that can only lead to tears.  I'll try to clarify the "best practices" approach in my answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are working with a shared resource between two threads so once might not be set to true when the Play is called for the second time. You can use a lock to allow executing part of your code by one thread at a time :

```
private readonly object lock_object=new object();
private void StartedPlaying_Once(object sender, TypedAudioFileEventArgs e)
{
lock(lock_object)
{    
if (!_once)
        _once = true;
    else
        Assert.Fail("Should not be called more than once!");
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, only I put my lock in the StartPlaying function before the call to QueueUserWork (another boolean checking if Sound is already being played in another thread). Still passes though :D

Comment: you are failing your test based on _once value so you should put your lock here (shared resource :) )

Comment: Thank you for the tip, hopefully if I keep fiddling around with that I'll eventually get it into a consistently failing state ^^

Answer (score 0):

Could those be failing outside the text execution? Your test ends right after you queue the item so I'm not sure what is happening to those threads when the test method ends its execution. Have you tried using `WaitHandle` to wait for the them to finish inside the test?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx for an example.

Comment: What do you mean after I queue the item? I call audioPlayer.StartPlaying() twice to see if it will fire the event twice. I don't stop after adding the file.